# ios6 UINavigationBar with more than 2 buttons

Tags: ios, button, user-interface, ios6, navigationbar

in my app i have a uinavigationbar with 3 buttons, but the code i used for ios5 does not seem to be good for ios6 anymore.
You can see a wrong-colored rect underneath my custum-view with two buttons on the right side.

heres the code i used, i found it somewhere on stackoverflow:

```
UIToolbar *tools = [[[UIToolbar alloc]
                     initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 110.0f, 44.01f)] autorelease]; // 44.01 shifts it up 1px for some reason
tools.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = NO;
tools.clipsToBounds = NO;
tools.translucent = self.headerbar.translucent;
tools.barStyle = self.headerbar.barStyle;  
tools.backgroundColor = self.headerbar.backgroundColor;
tools.tintColor = self.headerbar.tintColor;

NSMutableArray *buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

// Create a standard refresh button.
UIBarButtonItem *bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"heute" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(showThisWeek)];
bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
bi.width = 0;
[buttons addObject:bi];
//[bi release];

// Create a spacer.
bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:@selector(showThisWeek)];
[buttons addObject:bi];
//[bi release];

// Add profile button.
bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"vor" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(showNext)];
bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[buttons addObject:bi];
//[bi release];

// Add buttons to toolbar and toolbar to nav bar.
[tools setItems:buttons animated:NO];
[buttons release];
UIBarButtonItem *twoButtons = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools];
//[tools release];
header.rightBarButtonItem = twoButtons;
[header.leftBarButtonItem setAction:@selector(showPrevious)];
```

can someone hint me to a more elegant solution that works fine on both ios5 and ios6?

cheers
lukas

Answer (score 1):

Did you try leftBarButtonItems and rightBarButtonItems? You can add array of  buttons in left and right side nav bar using this.

If you use this, there will be no need for UIToolbar and their subviews.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried bar.style = -1?